# Fitting Gamma distribution to data in R using optim, ML

Tags: r, machine-learning, gamma

Im kinda new to R. I have a dataset, which also includes data of family income and I have to fit a Gamma distribution to this data, using the Maximum Likelihood Estimates. It is specifically told that we need to use the package optim, and not fitdistr. So this is my code:

```
t1 <- sum(log(newdata$faminc)) 
t2 <- sum(newdata$faminc)
obs <- nrow(newdata)
lh.gamma <- function(par) {
  -((par[1]-1)*t1 - par[2]*t2 - obs*par[1]*log(par[2]) - obs*lgamma(par[1]))
}

#initial guess for a = mean^2(x)/var(x) and b = mean(x) / var(x) 
a1 <- (mean(newdata$faminc))^2/var(newdata$faminc)
b1 <- mean(newdata$faminc)/var(newdata$faminc)

init <- c(a1,b1)
q <- optim(init, lh.gamma, method = "BFGS")
q
```

Also tried filling in just values in the init vector, and including this piece of code;

```
  dlh.gamma <- function(par){
  cbind(obs*digamma(par[1])+obs*log(par[2])-t2,
     obs*par[1]/par[2]-1/par[2]^2*t1)
}
```

and then the optim would look like :

```
 q <- optim(init, lh.gamma, dhl.gamma, method="BFGS")
```

None of it 'works'. First, when I tried the code at school computers, it gave me very huge numbers for the shape and rate parameters, which was not possible. Now, trying at home, I get this:

```
> q <- optim(init, lh.gamma, method = "BFGS")
Error in optim(init, lh.gamma, method = "BFGS") : 
  non-finite finite-difference value [2]
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> q
function (save = "default", status = 0, runLast = TRUE) 
.Internal(quit(save, status, runLast))
<bytecode: 0x000000000eaac960>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

q is not even 'created'. Except for when I include the dlh.gamma part above, but then I just get huge numbers again and no convergence.

Anybody who knows what goes wrong/what to do?

Edit:

```
> dput(sample(newdata$faminc, 500))
c(42.5, 87.5, 22.5, 17.5, 12.5, 30, 30, 17.5, 42.5, 62.5, 62.5, 
30, 30, 150, 22.5, 30, 42.5, 30, 17.5, 8.75, 42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 
62.5, 42.5, 30, 17.5, 87.5, 62.5, 150, 42.5, 150, 42.5, 42.5, 
42.5, 6.25, 62.5, 87.5, 6.25, 87.5, 30, 150, 22.5, 62.5, 42.5,    
150, 17.5, 42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 62.5, 22.5, 42.5, 42.5, 30, 62.5, 
30, 62.5, 87.5, 87.5, 42.5, 22.5, 62.5, 22.5, 8.75, 30, 30, 17.5, 
87.5, 8.75, 62.5, 30, 17.5, 22.5, 62.5, 42.5, 30, 17.5, 62.5, 
8.75, 62.5, 42.5, 150, 30, 62.5, 87.5, 17.5, 62.5, 30, 62.5, 
87.5, 42.5, 62.5, 30, 62.5, 42.5, 87.5, 150, 12.5, 42.5, 62.5, 
42.5, 62.5, 62.5, 150, 30, 87.5, 12.5, 17.5, 42.5, 62.5, 30, 
6.25, 62.5, 42.5, 12.5, 62.5, 8.75, 17.5, 42.5, 62.5, 87.5, 8.75, 
62.5, 30, 62.5, 87.5, 42.5, 62.5, 62.5, 12.5, 150, 42.5, 62.5,  
12.5, 62.5, 42.5, 62.5, 62.5, 87.5, 42.5, 62.5, 30, 42.5, 150, 
42.5, 30, 62.5, 62.5, 87.5, 42.5, 30, 62.5, 62.5, 42.5, 42.5, 
30, 62.5, 42.5, 42.5, 62.5, 62.5, 150, 42.5, 30, 42.5, 62.5, 
17.5, 62.5, 17.5, 150, 8.75, 62.5, 30, 62.5, 42.5, 42.5, 22.5, 
150, 62.5, 42.5, 62.5, 62.5, 22.5, 30, 62.5, 30, 150, 42.5, 42.5, 
42.5, 62.5, 30, 12.5, 30, 150, 12.5, 8.75, 22.5, 30, 22.5, 30, 
42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 30, 12.5, 62.5, 42.5, 30, 22.5, 42.5, 87.5, 
22.5, 12.5, 42.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 30, 42.5, 30, 62.5, 30, 62.5, 
12.5, 22.5, 42.5, 22.5, 87.5, 30, 22.5, 17.5, 42.5, 62.5, 17.5, 
250, 150, 42.5, 30, 42.5, 30, 62.5, 17.5, 87.5, 22.5, 150, 62.5, 
42.5, 6.25, 87.5, 62.5, 42.5, 30, 42.5, 62.5, 42.5, 87.5, 62.5, 
150, 42.5, 30, 6.25, 22.5, 30, 42.5, 42.5, 62.5, 250, 8.75, 150, 
42.5, 30, 42.5, 30, 42.5, 42.5, 30, 30, 150, 22.5, 62.5, 30, 
8.75, 150, 62.5, 87.5, 150, 42.5, 30, 42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 30, 8.75, 
42.5, 42.5, 30, 22.5, 62.5, 17.5, 62.5, 62.5, 42.5, 8.75, 42.5, 
12.5, 12.5, 150, 42.5, 42.5, 17.5, 42.5, 62.5, 62.5, 42.5, 42.5, 
30, 42.5, 62.5, 30, 62.5, 42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 22.5, 62.5, 62.5, 
62.5, 22.5, 150, 62.5, 42.5, 62.5, 42.5, 30, 30, 62.5, 22.5, 
62.5, 87.5, 62.5, 42.5, 42.5, 22.5, 62.5, 62.5, 30, 42.5, 42.5, 
8.75, 87.5, 42.5, 42.5, 87.5, 30, 62.5, 17.5, 62.5, 42.5, 17.5, 
22.5, 62.5, 8.75, 62.5, 22.5, 22.5, 22.5, 42.5, 17.5, 22.5, 62.5, 
42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 30, 30, 8.75, 30, 42.5, 62.5, 22.5, 
6.25, 30, 42.5, 62.5, 17.5, 62.5, 42.5, 8.75, 22.5, 30, 17.5, 
22.5, 62.5, 42.5, 150, 87.5, 22.5, 12.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 30, 
42.5, 22.5, 62.5, 87.5, 30, 42.5, 62.5, 22.5, 87.5, 30, 30, 22.5, 
87.5, 87.5, 250, 30, 62.5, 250, 62.5, 42.5, 42.5, 62.5, 62.5, 
42.5, 6.25, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 42.5, 42.5, 150, 62.5, 62.5, 30, 
150, 22.5, 87.5, 30, 150, 17.5, 8.75, 62.5, 42.5, 62.5, 150, 
42.5, 22.5, 42.5, 42.5, 17.5, 62.5, 17.5, 62.5, 42.5, 150, 250, 
22.5, 42.5, 30, 62.5, 62.5, 42.5, 42.5, 30, 150, 150, 42.5, 17.5, 
17.5, 42.5, 8.75, 62.5, 42.5, 42.5, 22.5, 150, 62.5, 30, 250, 
62.5, 87.5, 62.5, 8.75, 62.5, 30, 30, 8.75, 17.5, 17.5, 150, 
22.5, 62.5, 62.5, 42.5)
```

The faminc variable is in 1000s

Edit2:

Okay, the code is good, but now I try to fit the distribution over the histogram using the following:

```
x <- rgamma(500,shape=q$par[1],scale=q$par[2])
hist(newdata$faminc, prob = TRUE)
curve(dgamma(x, shape=q$par[1], scale=q$par[2]), add=TRUE, col='blue')
```

It just produces a flat blue line at the x-axis..

Comment: Please include `dput(newdata$faminc)` in your question.

Comment: There are 6547 observations..

Comment: If you are implying that knowing only the number of observations is sufficient for estimating your parameters then I think it's time to crack open your statistics textbook again...

Comment: You want me to include 6547 numbers in here? I don't understand.

Comment: A sample would be sufficient; maybe `dput(sample(newdata$faminc, 500))`.

Comment: @pvb1995 please view my edit in response to your second edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some things going on I haven't been able to work out, but here's a demonstration of the estimation.

Let's start by generating some data (so we know if the optimization is working). I only changed your optimization function below, and used Nelder-Mead instead of the quasi-Newton.

```
set.seed(23)
a <- 2 # shape
b <- 3 # rate

require(data.table)
newdata <- data.table(faminc = rgamma(10000, a, b))

t1 <- sum(log(newdata$faminc)) 
t2 <- sum(newdata$faminc)
obs <- nrow(newdata)

llf <- function(x){
  a <- x[1]
  b <- x[2]
  # log-likelihood function
  return( - ((a - 1) * t1 - b * t2 - obs * a * log(1/b) - obs * log(gamma(a))))
}

# initial guess for a = mean^2(x)/var(x) and b = mean(x) / var(x) 
a1 <- (mean(newdata$faminc))^2/var(newdata$faminc)
b1 <- mean(newdata$faminc)/var(newdata$faminc)

q <- optim(c(a1, b1), llf)
q$par
[1] 2.024353 3.019376
```

I'd say we're pretty close.

With your data:

```
(est <- q$par)
[1] 2.21333613 0.04243384

theoretical <- data.table(true = rgamma(10000, est[1], est[2]))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(newdata, aes(x = faminc)) + geom_density() + geom_density(data = theoretical, aes(x = true, colour = "red")) + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Not great, but reasonable for 500 obs.

**Response to OP Edit 2:**

You should look more closely at the functions you're using, `curve` accepts a function argument, not vector values:

```
gamma_density = function(x, a, b) ((b^a)/gamma(a)) * (x^(a - 1)) * exp(-b * x)
hist(newdata$faminc, prob = TRUE, ylim = c(0, 0.015))
curve(gamma_density(x, a = q$par[1], b = q$par[2]), add=TRUE, col='blue')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Im going to look into this a little bit further and try it myself, and try if it fits the histogram as its supposed to

Comment: You're a hero. Thank you very much. Im still trying to understand it, but I think Ill get there